# how to release file lock while mail attachment in loop in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, c#-4.0

i am sending single mail to more than 1 person. so i am sending mail in for loop with attachement.but while in second loop i am getting file lock error.below is my code.

```
public string SendMail(string toList, string from, string ccList,
string subject, string body)
{

    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    string msg = string.Empty;



    try
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(from);
        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.To.Add(toList);
        if (ccList != null && ccList != string.Empty)
            message.CC.Add(ccList);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = body;
        // We use gmail as our smtp client
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);

    if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
    {
        // File Upload path
        String FileName = FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName;


        FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FileName));


        //Getting Attachment file
        Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(Server.MapPath(FileName));
        //Attaching uploaded file
        message.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
    }   

        smtpClient.Send(message);
        LblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        LblMessage.Text = "Mail Sent Successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        LblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

    }
    return msg;
}
```

in loop calling this function

```
for (int i = 0; i < LbEmails.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                SendMail(LbEmails.Items[i].ToString(), TextBox1.Text, "", TbSubject.Text, TbBody.Text);

            }
```

Comment: "i am getting file lock error". What is the actual text of your error, and please indicate on which line the error occurs.

Comment: @spender Could not find file "filename" and then file is being used by another process.

Comment: @spender i am getting only first mail then after it shows  file is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're saving the uploaded file once for each email you send even though it seems to be the same for all the emails. Pull this line out of the `SendMail()` method and call it before your loop:

```
FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FileName));
```